# PHP Error Undefined Functions

Tags: eval, php

I am getting Error Undefined Function.

Here is the code:

```
$myvar = "@file_get_contents";

eval($myvar("http://someurlupdatehere.com"));

The error I get is: 

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function @file_get_contents() ..
```

Comment: Remove the error control operator lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks really weird to me what you are trying to do. I tend to say "Don't use eval, don't do that!" ;)

Anyway, here comes the right syntax:

```
$myvar = "@file_get_contents";
eval("$myvar('http://someurlupdatehere.com');");
```

Or if you need the return value of `file_get_contents()` in a variable (what is likely, use this:

```
$myvar = "@file_get_contents";
eval("\$file = $myvar('http://someurlupdatehere.com');");
echo $file;
```

Comment: The right syntax is `file_get_contents('http://someurlupdatehere.com');`, no eval

Comment: @OneTrickPony How can you say this, without knowing what OP is trying to do? Don't like such statements.

Comment: If the OP is trying to do anything else that this question suggests, (s)he should update the Q accordingly. Otherwise my statement remains valid

Answer (score 3):

`@file_get_contents()` is not a valid PHP function. You can remove the suppression operator to make this work:

```
$myvar = "file_get_contents";
```

If you still need to use the suppression operator, do:

```
eval('@' . $myvar("http://someurlupdatehere.com"));
```

or even leave the suppression operator and pass the entire line as a string:

```
$myvar = "@file_get_contents";
eval("$myvar('http://someurlupdatehere.com');");
```

Note that the use of the suppression operator and `eval` is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myvar = "file_get_contents";

eval(@$myvar("http://someurlupdatehere.com"));
?>
```

Works as well. Suppresses errors.